# Biztalk BAM Configuration Error : Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Instapi, Version=9.0.242.0

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010, biztalk-bam

I am trying to configure BAM since couple of days. I landed with below error

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo, Version=9.0.242.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I installed SQL server 2005 object collection and the above error gone. Later it started throwing below error,

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Instapi, Version=9.0.242.0,
```

Please find the below screens [image]

I have below sql software installed in machine.

[image]

Also below services are running in my machine. 
[image]

Please help, I am using only BizTalk in my machine, so please suggest what all are required and what I should delete. Apart what should I install so that I can see 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Instapi, Version=9.0.242.0' DLL. I have higher version 10.0... in my machine.

Answer (score 0):

As per this [blog by Simon Hart](http://www.simonrhart.com/2011/02/microsoft-notification-services-control.html)

> If you want BAM functionality in your BizTalk 2010 environment, do not
>   install the Notification Services MSI's referenced in the BizTalk 2010
>   install guide, instead install from the fully blown SQL Server 2005
>   ISO from MSDN Subscriptions.